# JavaFX default onAction effect

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

Can someone tell me how can i disable the default effect that occurs when clicking a button? When I click the text increases. (images below the code)

MAIN

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("iPTD_Fxml/MainScreen.fxml"));
        Scene mainScreen = new Scene(root);
        mainScreen.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScreen);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
package iPTD_Controllers;

import com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainScreenController implements Initializable {

    private static final String IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .50); -fx-background-radius: 15; -fx-border-radius: 15; -fx-border-color: #42f54e; -fx-font-weight: bold;";
    private static final String HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: rgba(84,84,84, .50); -fx-background-radius: 15; -fx-border-radius: 15; -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-font-weight: bold;";

    @FXML
    private Button buttonSettings;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonNewProject;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonOpenProject;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonAbout;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {}

    @FXML
    void onMouseEnterEvent(MouseEvent event) {
        Button eventButton = ((Button)event.getSource());
        eventButton.setStyle(HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE);
    }

    @FXML
    void onMouseExitEvent(MouseEvent event) {
        Button eventButton = ((Button)event.getSource());
        eventButton.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE);
    }

    @FXML
    public void onActionEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Button eventButton = ((Button)actionEvent.getSource());
        switch (eventButton.getId())
        {
            case "buttonClose":{
                ((Stage)((eventButton).getScene().getWindow())).close();
                eventButton.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE);
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("buttonNull");
        }
    }

}
```

NORMAL:

[image]

WHEN CLICKED: (would like to disable this text increase when you click a button)
OBS: When you make a quick click (click and release the button) the effect appears and exits, but if you keep pressing it, the effect will only exit when you stop pressing.

[image]

CSS:

```
#mainScreen_AnchorPane{
    -fx-background-radius: 50;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.button{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .50);
    -fx-background-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-color: #42f54e;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(84,84,84, .50);
    -fx-background-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-color: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Just guessing that you probably need to set the style for a pressed button as well as the default and hovered. I recommend using an external style sheet and using the proper pseudoclasses, instead of using listeners.

Comment: Hmm, i'll search about it, but there's a performance difference between usin pseudoclasses and listeners?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. It’s the preferred approach, because it separates the concerns properly (style is separated into a different place than layout), which is an order of magnitude more important than performance. Plus, obviously, the authors of the JavaFX library will optimise performance for the preferred approach, so without any evidence to the contrary, I’d assume that using an external style sheet in the preferred way would perform at least as well as using a non-preferred approach.

Comment: Yep, i got it, but i still need a solution, i tryed to replace every single event and nothing. Still increasing the text.

Comment: java naming conventions, please (remaining violation here: package name :)

Comment: don't understand why you want to do anything manually - hover is already a pseudo-class that's applied auto-magically. Anyway, look into the default style sheet (currently that's modena) to understand which states (and transitions) are available.

Comment: Ok, i did it, i edit the original post and put the CSS code there, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, i fix it by overwriting the "-fx-font-size:" style, thank you guys <3